# UnauthorizedOperation on terraform apply. How to run the following AWS config?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to deploy an infrastructure on AWS using terraform. This is the main.tf config file:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.27"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14.9"
}

provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
  ami           = "ami-830c94e3"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "ExampleAppServerInstance"
  }
}
```

AWS config file ~/.aws/config,:

```
[default]
region = us-east-1

[humboi]
region = us-east-1
```

Running terraform apply and entering "yes" gives:

```
aws_instance.app_server: Creating...
╷
│ Error: Error launching source instance: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: r8hvTFNQzGA7k309BxQ9OYRxCaCH-0wwYvhAzbjEt77PsyOYyWItWNrOPUW4Z1CIzm8A6x6euBuSZsE8uSfb3YdPuzLXttHT3DS9IJsDs0ilX0Vxtu1OZ3nSCBowuylMuLEXY8VdaA35Hb7CaLb-ktQwb_ke0Pku-Uh2Vi_cwsYwAdXdGVeTETkiuErZ3tAU37f5DyZkaL4dVgPMynjRI3-GW0P63WJxcZVTkfNcNzuTx6PQfdv-YydIdUOSAS-RUVqK6ewiX-Mz4S0GwAaIFeJ_4SoIQVjogbzYYBC0bI4-sBSyVmySGuxNF6x-BOU0Zt2-po1mwEiPaDBVL9aOt6k_eZKMbYM9Ef8qQRcxnSLWOCiHuw6LVbmPJzaDQRFNZ2eO11Fa2oOcu8JMEOQjOtPkibQNAdO_5LZWAnc6Ye2-Ukt2_folTKN6TH6v1hmwsLAO7uGL60gQ-n9iBfCIqEE_6gfImsdbOptgz-IRtTrz5a8bfLOBVfd9oNjKGXQoA2ZKhM35m1ML1DQKY8LcDv0aULkGzoM6bRYoq1UkJBYuF-ShamtSpSlzpd4KDXztpxUdb496FR4MdOoHgS04W_3WXoN-hb_lG-Wgbkv7CEWMv2pNhBCRipBgUUw3QK-NApkeTxxJXy9vFQ4fTZQanEIQa_Bxxg
│   status code: 403, request id: 0c1f14ec-b5f4-4a3f-bf1f-40be4cf370fc
│ 
│   with aws_instance.app_server,
│   on main.tf line 17, in resource "aws_instance" "app_server":
│   17: resource "aws_instance" "app_server" {
│ 
╵
```

The error is that the Operation was Unauthorized. What's the cause of the unauthorized operation if I have the ~/.aws/config and also the ~/.aws/credentials?

Comment: Does your account have permission to perform this operation?

Answer (score 0):

I have this happen when I change my backend configuration without deleting `.terraform`. I believe terraform caches credentials in `.terraform`. If you delete that directory, it will regenerate it and it might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you restart your machine after setting environment variables for aws.

Answer (score 0):

The IAM User which you have created

> doesn't have Admin access or EC2 FULL ACESS

so enable it and try it again..